# .children() does not work on specified index of jquery return

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeerror

I'm trying to get the children of the *n*th element returned by a jquery call. For example:

`var kids = $('div')[7].children();`

However, I keep getting this error with respect to `children()`:

`Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function`

Can someone explain why this happens? `children()` works fine as long as I'm not calling it on an indexed element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because it is no longer a [jQuery object](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/) after you specify an index `[7]`. Thus, you are calling a jQuery method on a DOM element (which doesn't work).

You could use the [`.eq()` method](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) instead:

```
$('div').eq(7).children();
```

You could also use:

```
$($('div')[7]).children();
```

It's worth pointing out that this would work because the DOM element is wrapped in `$()` - thus turning it into a jQuery object.

Answer (score 1):

You're using children method in javascript object i.e. `$('div')[7]`. To work with jquery method you need to use jquery object instead of javascript object.

Use [eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq) method:

```
var kids = $('div').eq(7).children();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use array syntax with a jquery list you get back a document node, not a jquery element. Use `$('div').eq(7).children()` instead.